# How can I access an object outside of the specific function?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a function to create a level. This function "drawLevel(level)" is creating walls, the end and the player. Since I want the player to move after I put in the directions, I have to access the functions of the object "player". Yet it still tells me that player is not defined yet. Is there a simple way to change that or what am I missing?
P.S. pxl(1) equals 80

```
levels =[[  "WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
            "W          EW",
            "W         WWW",
            "W   WWWW    W",
            "W   W       W",
            "WWWWW  WWWW W",
            "W   W     W W",
            "W   W     W W",
            "WP          W",
            "WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        ]]

def drawLevel(level):
    x = y = 0

    walls = []

    ends = []

    players = []

    for row in levels[level]:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                wall = Wall((x, y))
                walls.append(wall)
            if col == "E":
                end = End((x, y))
                ends.append(end)
            if col == "P":
                player = Player((x,y))
                players.append(player)
            x += 80
        y += 80
        x = 0
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, wall.rect)
    for end in ends:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, end.rect)
    for player in players:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, player.rect)
    
    return players
    return walls
    return ends
```

```
def movePlayer():
    for i in range(len(move_list)):
        if move_list[i] == 1:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(-1))
        elif move_list[i] == 2:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(1))
        elif move_list[i] == 3:
            player.move(pxl(1), pxl(0))
        elif move_list[i] == 4:
            player.move(pxl(-1), pxl(0))
```

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], pxl(1), pxl(1))

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        # Bewegung für x und y. Kollision wird überprüft
        if dx != 0:
            self.wallCollisionDetection(dx, dy)(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.wallCollisionDetection(dx, dy)(0, dy)

    def wallCollisionDetection(self, dx, dy):
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0:  
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0:  
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0:  
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0:  
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
```

```
def main_loop_state_config():
    global level, end_rect, place_y, curr_moves, max_moves
    screen.fill(WOODY)
    drawRect()
    drawGrid()
    drawLevel(level)
    players = drawLevel(level)
    walls = drawLevel(level)
    ends = drawLevel(level)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                print("Spiel wird beendet!")
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:               
                        move_list.append(1)
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        move_list.append(2)
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        move_list.append(3)
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                        move_list.append(4)
                elif event.key == K_0:
                        movePlayer()
```

Comment: You need to add "global" statements in all the functions that refer to external variables, as you've done for "main_loop_state_config()"

Comment: @MarkLavin Sorry, but this is wrong. There is a list of `payers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of players. You have to decide which player you want to move.
e.g. move the 1st player in the list.

Add a *player* argument to the `movePlayer` function:

```py
def movePlayer(player):
    for i in range(len(move_list)):
        if move_list[i] == 1:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(-1))
        elif move_list[i] == 2:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(1))
        elif move_list[i] == 3:
            player.move(pxl(1), pxl(0))
        elif move_list[i] == 4:
            player.move(pxl(-1), pxl(0))
```

Pass the 1st player form the list to `movePlayer`:

```py
elif event.key == K_0:
    movePlayer(players[0])
```

---

Alternatively, you can make `movePlayer` a method of class `Player`.

Comment: exactly what I was going to write. +1